# loses opacity when 2 brushes overlap each other

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

When user brushes with colored brush, it blends with background as expected. But when continues brushing nothing going wrong opacity maintains as per requirement But it goes wrong when user draws two lines (not continuous) [soft alpha edges loses opacity when 2 brushes overlap each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l35p3.png)

Comment: unexpectedly Image was given as a link to the body....

Comment: Used BiezerPath for drawing

Comment: R u using UIBezerPaths for drawing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call  `- (void)strokeWithBlendMode:(CGBlendMode)blendMode alpha:(CGFloat)alpha;` UIBexerPath's  method from drawRect: of your view class. **blendmode** suitable parameter are [CGBlendMode constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGBlendMode). I used **kCGBlendModeCopy** for same situation it worked for me. You can also use same Constant or You can play with CGBlendMode constants to get out of this.

```
- (void)drawRect
{
        [bezierPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:1.0];

}
```

Comment: Can u xplain somewhat in brief... i couldn't make it work in my app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705542/objective-c-paint-how-to-avoid-two-brush-strokes-over-each-other-which-make-it?noredirect=1#comment29271242_19705542

Comment: instead of using kCGBlendModeNormal constant use kCGBlendModeCopy constant and check how it will be. If still your facing issue you just check one by one constant from this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGBlendMode

Comment: Thank u so much ajay... solved the issue by replacing kCGBlendModeNormal with kCGBlendModeCopy

Comment: It's my Pleasure. Here people appreciate  people's  work by giving vote up for answer and  accepting correct suitable answer. Don't forget to accept answer if its functioning for you.